# Identify Webserver & Script of a website

Tags: html, iis

I have got two simple questions

1. How can I tell what server is a website on? I remember I used to read the HTTP Host Header to identify the type of server. Is there any tool to do it?

2a. A lot of the website have the page extension .html and you just know they are not html. How can I tell what programming language is behind them? 
2b. For ASPX, I think IIS can map the extension, so it will show HTML instead of ASPX, right?

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.

Yes, you can check the http header tag "SERVER". Example of responses:
-Microsoft-IIS/6.0
-GFE/1.3
-Server Apache/2.2.11 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.2.6-3ubuntu4.2 with Suhosin-Patch

You can also check "X-Powered-By" on some servers, example:
-PHP/5.2.6-3ubuntu4.2
-ASP.NET

You can do this in firefox/firebug for example. Go to NET pick a request, select headers and check under response headers. You could do this is Fiddler to or any other http sniffer.

2a)
See my first answer

2b)
Yes you can map .html or anything as a "asp.net" extension, meaning that the extension will be handled by the web application. Common use is that you have a httphandler that catches that extension in web.config.

Not sure what your endgoal of these questions are.. or rather to what purpose, maybe we could answer better then.

Answer (score 1):

1. Look at the HTTP headers. This works as long as the Server admin hasn't disabled them (which he usually doesn't).

Try http://kalender-365.de/ip/get-http-header.php

2a. This actually works with all servers and all extensions. Some Interpreters - such as e.g. PHP - send a special created-by HTTP header (which can be disabled, however).

Comment: Thanks very much about Q1.

Question 2a. Do you mean it can only tell by looking at the HTTP Header? I wanna know site like this one www.australianidol.com.au, what's behind it? I can see it's Apache Server, so it's can be anything but ASPX. 

Cheers

Comment: Actually, you only can hope you get an http header. There is no other even remotely reliable way of knowing.